# Is there any Keychain extension for Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, keychain, password

I am using 1Password, but it's not free and I'm thinking about migrating to free OS app - Keychain. Is there anything similar to 1Password extension but for Kechain? I want to use the Keychain only for logins in Chrome and often using many logins to the single page.

I like the way 1Password works. I simply click on the icon and select the username. The extension automatically fills in login details and logs me in. Can I do the same on Chrome with Apple Keychain?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there's no official way to do what you want and I recommend you to avoid third parts extensions available somewhere on the internet that could endanger your passwords and personal datas. You can use your Google Account Keychain but you will be able to use the passwords stored on it only on chrome browsers signed and synchronized with your Google Account.